# Height and Width values don't work on Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing a Kivy app on Python and wanted to place my widgets relative to the height and width of the main layout but it doesn't work till I manually change the size of app on pc, which is not allowed manually on Android.

Here is .py code:

```
from kivy.app import Appfrom kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class UI(Widget):
    pass


class UIApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return UI()


app = UIApp()
app.run()
```

And .kv part:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<UI>:
    padding: root.height*.05,root.height*.05
    spacing: root.height*.05,root.height*.05
    
    Label:
        center_x: root.width*.25
        center_y: root.height*.9
        text: "Hello World"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        size: root.width*.3, root.height*.06
        font_size: root.height*.03
```

Comment: Your `UI` widget extends `Widget`, so it does not have the capability to handle position and size of its children. Try changing `class UI(Widget):` to `class UI(FloatLayout):`

Comment: Nope, changings over the code still don't solve my problem. I re-wrote the code with your idea  but error still occurs. It uses the given scales but initial position is coordinated different from the Kivy coordinate system. After scaling the window manually, everything perfectly fixes.

Comment: Still a nice advice, thanx

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, you need to add `size_hint: None, None`. Otherwise, your `size:` will have no effect.

Comment: I did but it still doesnt solve my problem. I rewrote the entire code for FloatLayout but error still occurs.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No, The window shows up but all things settled up for a different origin around 100, 100 point or something around there. When I resize the window, calculations are correcten theirselves.